# Career, where is "current position" used?

Tags: support, profile-page

When editing our profile we are able to provide the *current position* like shown below:

> [image]

Where is this information shown or used? I am not able to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's shown just under your name on your "Profile" tab -- but only if you left the "Title" field blank when editing your profile.

Comment: oh right! it should be said somewhere by the way ....